# How to tailor an NLTK chatbot's response using macro variables (Python)

Tags: python, chat, nltk, chatbot

I've been playing around with the NLTK package in Python, in particular `nltk.chat.util`.
I have been able to create a few simple chatbots by defining my `pairs` e.g. if you say 'Hi' the chatbot will either say 'Hey' or 'Hello' back:

```
pairs = (  
          (r'Hi',
             ("Hey",
              "Hello")
          )
        )
```

A useful feature here is that you can use wildcards and macro variables, for example:

```
pairs = (  
          (r'My name is (.*)',
             ("Hey %1",
              "Hello %1")
          )
        )
```

So if I were to say 'My name is Grace', it would return 'Hey Grace' or 'Hello Grace'.

What I want to be able to do, is some cool stuff with the macro variable. My aim is to get the chatbot to read a certain line of a file to me based on what I input. What I want the code to be is:

```
ExpP = open("ExpensePolicy.txt", "r")

pairs = (
          (r'Read me line (.*) of the expenses policy',
             (ExpP.readline(%1),
              "No")
          )
        )
```

But when `%1` is taken out of the quotation marks it no longer recognises it as a variable. Also, when it is inside quotation marks inside a function, it just treats it as literally the string `"%1"`.

Another thing I was trying to do, was change the first letter of the macro variable. So if someone input 'You are funny', where 'funny' is `%1`, I want the chatbot to return 'You are punny' (for example). I tried using `%1.replace(%1[:1], "p")`, but again, it does not like the use of the `%1`.

Is there any way to combine the use of macro variables in `nltk.chat.util` and other commands / functions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

here's my two cents.
I've made it work by using eval(), this way:

```
pairs = [
  [r"how is the weather in (.*)", ["In %1 it's a sunny day", eval("dynResponse('%1')")]]
]

def dynResponse(val):
 return "Hello " + val
```

**BUT:**

1. Keep in mind that this approach is totally insecure, because eval does evaluate everythings may arrive from an http request.
2. Using eval is not an elegant way to deal with this kind of things. It would be preferable using a NLTK built-in mechanism to achieve dynamic values in pairs (which today, for my ignorance, I'm not aware of).

Glad to add to this interesting topic!
Bye.